# Filtering nested _source properties in Kibana

Tags: logstash, kibana-5

I'm looking for some guidance on how to setup my `logstash`/`elastic`/`kibina` config to most effectively query my `rabbitmq` logs.

What I want to do is query and visualise nested properties within my `_source` object.

For example my `_source` might look like this:

```
{
    "ApplicationName": "MyApp",
    "JsonPayload": 
        { 
            "ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException",
            "Message":"Some details about the exception"
        }         
}
```

I am able to see `ApplicationName` and `JsonPayload` listed in my discover fields in kibana, but I am unable to do anything with the nested fields `ExceptionType` and `Message`.

I presume I need to flatten out the `JsonPayload` object for Kibana to work with it, but I'm unsure where to do this:

- Can I write a query in Kibana for this?
- Do I do something with elastic search to enable this?
- Do I need to adjust some mapping in Logstash?

I'm new to the stack so unsure which of the tools is the most appropriate place to do this.

I'm using logstash and kibana 5.5 if this helps.

Comment: One way to do it would be to use the [json filter plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-json.html) to parse the json and then use the add_filter in the filter option to manually flatten your document.

Comment: add_field, not add_filter.

Comment: I made a more severe error than I documented here, namely that my JsonPayload was stringified. 
I used the `json` filter to get those fields out